# Show that if $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed and $|b| < 1$, then $n^kb^n \longrightarrow 0$ when $n\longrightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that if $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed and $|b| < 1$, then $n^kb^n \longrightarrow 0$ when $n\longrightarrow \infty$

I have been struggling with this prove. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Write $n^{k}b^{n}=\frac{n^{k}}{1/b^{n}}$, then apply L'Hopital's rule to the limit repeatedly. As a simple case, consider the limit as $n\to\infty$, for $n/b^{n}$. It certainly tends to $0$ upon one application of$L-Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may apply the ratio test:
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)^{k}b^{n+1}}{n^{k}b^{n}}\right| = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{k}|b| = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{k}|b| = |b| < 1
\end{align*}

Consequently, the corresponding series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{k}b^{n} = b + 2^{k}b^{2} + 3^{k}b^{3} + \ldots
\end{align*}
converges. Hence we conclude that $a_{n}\to 0$ just as desired.

Answer (score 2):

This is a method using the binomial formula only. We may assume that $0<b<1$. Accordingly $b=(1+\varepsilon)^{-1}$ with $\varepsilon>0$. But $(1+\varepsilon)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}\varepsilon^j>\binom{n}{k+1}\varepsilon^{k+1}$ for $n>k$. Then $0<n^k b^n<\frac{n^k}{\binom{n}{k+1}\varepsilon^{k+1}}\leq c (\frac{n}{n-k})^k \frac1{n-k}$ with some positive constant $c$. But the last expression tends to $0$ for $n\to\infty$ implying the desired result.

---

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$c = \frac{1}{b} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $|b| \lt 1$, you have $|c| \gt 1$. You are thus trying to determine

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^k}{c^n} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

The numerator and the absolute value of the denominator both go to $\infty$. As [Representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/722514/representation)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673961/show-that-if-k-in-mathbbn-is-fixed-and-b-1-then-nkbn-longrighta/3673966#comment7549824_3673961) indicates, use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) $k$ times on the numerator and denominator to get the limit is $0$ since the numerator will be the fixed $k!$ then, but the absolute value of the denominator will still be going to $\infty$.